# Solve the system:$\,\small\begin{eqnarray}a_1P+b_1Q+c_1R&=&0\\ a_2P+b_2Q+c_2R&=&0\\ a_3P+b_3Q+c_3R&=&0 \end{eqnarray}$ where $\small PQR\neq 0$

Tags: diophantine-equations, matrix-equations

Consider the system of diophantine equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
a_1P+b_1Q+c_1R&=&0\\
a_2P+b_2Q+c_2R&=&0\\
a_3P+b_3Q+c_3R&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
where $PQR\neq 0$.
What is the easiest method to solve it?

What I have done: I calculated instead the ratios:
$\dfrac{P}{R} $ and
$\dfrac{Q}{R} $. 
I obtained for each 3 equivalent ratios. There it gets pretty cumbersome and I got lost. I wonder if there is easier method?

Comment: Without knowing more about $a_i, b_i, c_i$, you cannot solve this system. For example, if $a_i=b_i=c_i=0$ for all values of $i$, then any triple of $P,Q,R$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no unique solution. The system can be written as
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}P\\Q\\R\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right).$$

- If $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
  a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
  a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
  \end{array}\right)$ is non-singular, then the above system has the unique solution $\left(\begin{array}{c}P\\Q\\R\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$. However, this is in contradiction with $PQR\not=0$. Hence, there is no solution.
- If $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
  a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
  a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
  \end{array}\right)$ is singular, then the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: If the matrix $A$ is singular, then $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions...

Comment: Ah yes, well then there are either no or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I believe you mean to say that if the matrix is non-singular, then the above system has the unique solution $(P,Q,R)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @Eric, $Ax=0$ always has a solution as $x=0$ solves it. No solution could happen to a $Ax=b\ne 0$

Comment: @Eric, thanks for your input. But I am particularly interested in the forms of those solutions.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl, that depends on the values of $a_1,\ldots,c_3$. Do you know anything about them in particular or do you want to know it in general?

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Eric S. said, if the matrix is non-singular, then there is no nonzero solution. But if it is singular, then the column vectors are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, which means, by definition, that we can write them as a linear combination of each other with nonzero rational coefficients. And this can be done with integers, as we're free to clear denominators.

This will be a solution with $PQR\ne 0$ as long as none or all of the columns are multiples of each other. If columns $a$ and $b$ are multiples of each other, then the images is going to be either 2 or 1 dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$. If it is two dimensional, then the kernel is exactly the subspace with $R=0$ so there are no solutions with $PQR\ne 0$. If the image is one dimensional, then every column is a multiple of every other column and the kernel is two dimensional and so we can make $PQR\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as the system  $Ax=b$, i.e.
$$\pmatrix{
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
}\pmatrix{P\\Q\\R}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$$

Since you say that $PQR\ne 0$ you say that there is a dependency between the equations, i.e. this system can be transformed to an equivalent linear system with at most two equation, i.e. 1 equation or 2 equations. This would mean that the system has at least $1$ degree of freedom, perhaps even  $2$.

If the system has one degree of freedom the solution will depend on a free choice of one of the unknowns, e.g. $P=f(R)$ and $Q=g(R)$, which would mean that given $R$ you can adjust your $P,Q$ such that  it solves the system.

For two degrees of freedom your system is equivalent to one equation only and therefore your solution will be of the form of $P=f(Q,R)$ where $Q,R$ you can choose as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So are you implying that I can assume that, for instance: $\gcd(a_1, a_2)=\gcd(b_1,b_2)=\gcd(c_1,c_2)>1$?

Comment: This could happen. However, the dependence could be more "complicated" then just one equation is multiple of another. For example in the following system
$\pmatrix{x+y+z=0\\3x+5y-2z=0\\4x+6y-z=0}$
the third line is sum of the first two, so doesn't give any new information.